# How to solve my assignment pd.read_csv function?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, function, csv

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxlTm.png)I have an assignment, I have to use the function [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roPQZ.png)' pd.read_csv 'on a file and it keep telling me that the file doesn't exist and sending me errors

a​nd I did upload it to jupyter notebooks already

Comment: Please don't post images of text like code, errors, data... we'd prefer a [mcve] though!

Comment: Can you share the code used and the errors you're getting ?

Comment: you 'll find it in the image description

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter the .csv file path correctly.

df = pd.read_csv("your_csv_file_path") 
print(df)

Comment: data = pd.read_csv('happyscore')
print(data)
I did type the name correctly

Comment: Your question has already been answered here: <br/> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58185487/how-to-read-csv-file-into-jupyter-notebook